# Use Keyboard Shortcut to Open .py File in Editor Window

Tags: python, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to open an existing .py file in the Python editor window using only a keyboard shortcut.

I have created a script that opens the file I am trying to open:

```
    open(r'path\to\file.py')
```

and created a shortcut to this script and added a keyboard shortcut in the shortcuts properties window.

When I run the shortcut, it only runs the file but does not open it in the editor window.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with:

```
import os
file_path = "C:/file/path/python_file.py"
os.system('notepad.exe ' + file_path)
```

or:

```
import subprocess
file_path = "C:/file/path/python_file.py"
subprocess.call(["C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.4/bin\pycharm64.exe", file_path])
```

Comment: Thanks. This will open the code within notepad, correct? I am trying to open with the Python editor window.

Comment: @reevesii check my edit, for example to open with pycharm

Comment: running the code below only seems to run the script then close: 

```import subprocess
file_path = r'C:\Users\my.name\Desktop\file.py'
subprocess.call([r'C:\Users\my.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\pythonw.exe',
                 file_path])```

Comment: @reevesii In Python 3, add the following to the end of your code:

input('Press ENTER to exit')
This will cause the program to wait for user input, with pressing ENTER causing the program to finish.

Answer (score 0):

- Change the preferences in Python (In IDLE, Options>Configure IDLE>General tab) so that At Startup is Open Edit Window.
- (I changed my default program to idle.bat, but I think I could have simply used the step above instead)
- Then make a shortcut to the .py file.
- Change Properties in the short cut by typing a letter in the Shortcut Key cell.

Now when I push ctrl-alt-w, this file opens up in the editor window.